# Isn't there any way to select attributes from multiple tables by non-pk-column with hitting DB once in Django model?

Tags: python, sql, django, join

I apologize for my overlong title.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    menu_code = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)    # It expresses order of menu items so it often can be changed.
    menu_title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    submenu_title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class Board(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
```

Above is a part of my models.py.
And what I want to do is just like below in SQL.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Board B, Menu M 
WHERE
    B.menu_id=M.menu_id and 
    M.menu_title='cat';
```

or

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Board B INNER JOIN Menu M
ON
    B.menu_id=M.menu_id and
    M.menu_title='cat';
```

I've seen many questions and answers about it and they supposed to use 'select_related', but mine has a slight difference with their problems.

- 'menu_title' isn't a PK of Menu table, so filter method of Board table cannot find that attribute.

Is there any solution? Or do I have to change my model design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah,You can simply use double underscore ( __ )  to get **menu_title** of **Menu** Model with prefetch_related(),

The resulting query set will be like this :

```
query_set = Board.objects.filter(menu__menu_title = "cat").prefetch_related('menu')
```

Becuase your model **Board** has a foreign key  **menu** to **Menu** Model.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works.
I think I was confused of the usage of double underscore. Maybe I should google more carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things first. `Menu` does not have a `menu_id` field. Your question references one. Did you mean the implicitly created `id`?

You should be able to write a raw SQL query that does the join, and then extract the data and build your instance manually.

But that will be painful.

It would be easier if you added the foreign key relationship in your model. Is there a reason why you are reluctant to do that?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't have menu_id in the code cause it is implicitly created.
The problem I was struggling is simply that I didn't know that I can simply access to foreign table with double underscore.
I think I should google more before I ask next time. Thank you.